# Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 3.11 — what's the meaning of this kind of induced norm?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm) there is a definition of induced norm. In [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), Boyd & Vandenberghe extend the induced norm:

---

> As a generalization suppose $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$ are norms on $\mathbf R^p$ and $\mathbf R^q$, respectively.
> The induced norm of a matrix $X \in \mathbf R^{p\times q}$ is defined as
> $$\|X\|_{a,b}=\sup_{v\ne0}\frac{\|Xv\|_a}{\|v\|_b}.$$
> (This reduces to the spectral norm when both norms are Euclidean.) The induced
> norm can be expressed as
> \begin{align*}
> \|X\|_{a,b}&=\sup\{\|Xv\|_a \mid \|v\|_b=1\}\\
> &=\sup\{u^TXv \mid \|u\|_{a^*}=1, \|v\|_b=1\}
> \end{align*}
> where $\|\cdot\|_{a^*}$ is the dual norm of $\|\cdot\|_a$ and we use the fact that $$\|z\|_a=\sup\{u^Tz \mid \|u\|_{a^*}=1\}.$$

---

[image]

---

Please explain the meaning of the generalized norm. Why can $a$ and $b$ be different? What is the meaning of each one?

Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From which section of the book?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo In the pdf-file linked in the question, this is Example 3.11.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Indeed. Matches my years-old version. Thank you. Updated the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The induced norm tells us the maximum amount that a vector can get stretched out by $X$. But in order for this statement to make sense, we need to have a way of measuring the sizes of vectors in $\mathbb R^p$, and also a way of measuring the sizes of vectors in $\mathbb R^q$. That's what the norms $\| \cdot \|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$ do for us.

There's no reason that we should restrict ourselves to using, say, Euclidean norms.

Comment: Again you!  Except  $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$, there may exist $c$ and $d$ norm in $p$ and $q$ space. I want to know the generalized meaning . Thx!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "generalized meaning".  We might choose $\| \cdot \|_a$ to be, for example, the $\ell_1$-norm, or the $\ell_2$-norm, or $\ell_\infty$-norm, or $\ell_{2,1}$-norm,etc, etc, and similar choices are available for $\| \cdot \|_b$.  Each norm has its own way of being visualized, and its own reasons for being useful in various situations.  Many different norms are popular.  When we define the induced norm of a matrix, we might as well make the definition as general as possible.  If nothing else, it would be inelegant to be unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstand your answer at first.. But I still do not get the *difference* in your answer. What happens when $a = 2$ and $b = 1$? I don't know why they could be different..

Comment: An example may help: suppose that $\| \cdot \|_b$ is the $\ell_\infty$-norm and $\| \cdot \|_a$ is the $\ell_1$-norm and $X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  Can you see what $\| X \|_{a,b}$ is equal to then?

Comment: It is equal to the num of nonzero elements of $Xv$ over the max element of $v$ ..But it seems to be meaningless besides maths..

Comment: But can you tell me specifically what number it's equal to?  Is it equal to $4$?  I don't think I have a more enlightening interpretation of what $\| X \|_{a,b}$ means than just "it tells you the maximum amount that a vector can get stretched out by $X$, when we use $\| \cdot \|_a$ and $\| \cdot \|_b$ to measure the sizes of vectors in $\mathbb R^p$ and $\mathbb R^q$, respectively."  If you want to quantify how "large" a matrix $X$ is, then it does not seem like a bad idea to ask "How large can the output possibly be, when the input has norm $1$?"

Comment: If $\|v\|_\infty = 1$ with all elements $1$, then it is equal to $3$. I get your point! Thank you very much!